# How to define a method which contains pointers from other class?

Tags: c++

[Diagram of classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba0U2.jpg)
I am having trouble making the addArticle method from the attached diagram. I cant grasp how to add elements from the class Article to the Invoice with method addArticle. After the elements are added with the method, the method print should print out all the added elements.

The only thing so far I have able to come up with is this

```
void Invoice::addArticle(Article *a) {

}
```

my header file

```
class Invoice {
private:
    std::string seller;
    int id;
    static int countId;

public:
    explicit Invoice(std::string seller);
    void addArticle(Article* a);
    ~Invoice();
    void print();
};
```

Comment: And what exactly is unclear to you? How to store an array of pointers in a class?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: In a data member of type `std::vector<Article*>`, for example.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @Badonka Could you make that more precise? Are you unclear on how to store [something] in a class? How to declare [something] to be an array (of whatever) in a class? How to declare an array to be an array of pointers? More than one of these?